# Loading string into XML Data

Tags: c#, xml

I am developing an application where I am reading a file, converting the contents into string and then loading the string in XML. But the issue that I am facing is that while loading the string data into XML I am getting an exception of invalid characters. I am using the following piece of code. Could any one help me to resolve the issue. Thank you in advance.

```
ZipFileEntry objContactXML;

String xmlData = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(objContactXML.FileData);

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlData);
```

Regards,
Sanchaita

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, this is a nasty bit of code:

```
ASCIIEncoding.UTF8
```

Please use just `Encoding.UTF8` - it's UTF-8, not ASCII.

Now, you *can* create a `StringReader` around your XML text data - but you'd actually be better off not turning it into string data at all. It may be encoded in something other than UTF-8 - and the XML parser knows how to deal with that. It's entirely possible that this is why you're running into problems with your current approach. Leave the data in binary and parse that:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(objContactXML.FileData))
{
    document.Load(stream);
}
```

As an aside, if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, I would *strongly* advise you to use LINQ to XML (`XDocument` etc) instead of the old DOM API. LINQ to XML is a *much* nicer API.

In LINQ to XML, you'd use:

```
XDocument document;
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(objContactXML.FileData))
{
    document = XDocument.Load(stream);
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same exception even after trying the above piece of code.

Comment: @Sanchaita: Then that suggests the data isn't valid XML. It's unclear whether it was originally invalid, or whether your ZipFileEntry class is causing a problem - where does that come from?